# DB2 ERROR on OPEN Cursor, Sqlcode : -818

Tags: db2

I am running a VC++ 6.0 program which is accessing DB2 database. I have SQG file which containt the SQL command. 
I am getting DB2 ERROR on OPEN Cursor, Sqlcode : -818 error when executing the program.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do a recompile or a rebind.  According to the documentation for [SQL818](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0818.htm):

"Bind the application again, using the bind file for the program that matches the object module. Or, execute the program that corresponds to the package stored in the database."